# How do I begin integrating this one? $\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-t-t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Before I ask my next question, I think this is a great forum, and wish I could know more about the collective people who post here (types of careers that use math? grad students?

What are your non-Math interests? Is there an "Off-topic" subforum on StackExchange?  I'd love to know what else you guys engage with in life...and what else interests you folks...or what your non-work/math goals in life are)

Another big thanks to people who help others here. I can't say it enough.

Anyways...How do I begin integrating this one?
$$\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-t-t^2}dt$$

I don't think this is a u/du substitution.
Do I change it to this?
$$\int_0^x (1-t-t^2)^{-1} dt=$$

***Disclaimer: I am not a student posting his homework assignment.  I am an adult learning Calculus.***

Comment: Hint: Complete the square.

Comment: Substitute $u = \left(t+\frac12\right)$. You get $\int_{1/2}^{x+1/2} \frac{du}{5/4 - u^2}$, which you probably know how to handle. Or do a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Look in your textbook for "partial fractions" .... there may be a section called "integrating rational functions" but maybe only stuck in the middle of "methods of integration".

Comment: Ok, so the bottom line is this is an advanced integration technique that I have yet to encounter?  I will look it up, or revisit at a later date. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure where to go from here:  $$\int_0^x\frac{1}{\frac{5}{4}-u^2}du$$             Also not sure how to change limits of integration.  What topic should I look up, in order how to do this?  I have not encountered this method when learning basic u/du substitution for indefinite integrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write the integrand as $\dfrac{1}{5/4- (t+1/2)^2}$

Comment: Are there poles within the integration interval?

Comment: Depends on the value of $x$.

Comment: Ok, so the bottom line is this is an advanced integration technique that I have yet to encounter?  I will look it up, or revisit at a later date. Thanks!

Comment: No, actually it is not advanced at all. I have just completed the square, now you just need to substitute $u=t + 1/2$ and split into partial fractions, then you can integrate. You will need to use $\int \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \ln{x}+C$

Comment: Not sure where to go from here:  $$\int_0^x\frac{1}{\frac{5}{4}-u^2}du$$             Also not sure how to change limits of integration.  What topic should I look up, in order how to do this?  I have not encountered this method when learning basic u/du substitution for indefinite integrals

Comment: Write the integrand as $$\frac{A}{\sqrt{5}/2-u}+\frac{B}{\sqrt{5}/2+u}$$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants to be found.